# Как завернуть шаблон в шаблон Spring boot FreeMaker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemaker

У меня есть некий контроллер вида:

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class Login {
    @RequestMapping(value = "auth")
    public String auth() {
        return "login/auth";
    }
}
```

Где `login/auth` это путь до файла `auth.ftl`. В качестве шаблонизатора использую `FreeMaker`.

Что я хочу: у меня есть некий шаблон `content.ftl` с содержанием:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>...</head>
<body>${content}</body>
```

В который должны передаваться данные из метода `auth()` и уже после отображаться.

В целом я понимаю логику: наследуемся от какого-то класса шаблонизатора, сначала рендерим `auth.ftl`, потом кидаем данные в `content.ftl`, опять рендерним и отдаем данные уже в браузер. Но где взять пример? `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1: вклиниваемся в рендеринг**

Если мы заставим Spring резолвить имя view в подконтрольный нам объект, то сможем рендерить его как захотим. Чтобы это сделать, подсунем Spring'у view resolver, который будет выдавать наши view:

```
// Наш view resolver, проксирующий вызовы к настоящему
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver) {
    FreeMarkerWrappedViewResolver viewResolver =
        new FreeMarkerWrappedViewResolver(freeMarkerViewResolver);
    // Так как в контексте будет и наш, и настоящий view resolver,
    // нужно заставить Spring применять наш раньше настоящего.
    // Этого можно добиться, установив order в значение поменьше.
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    return viewResolver;
}

// Настоящий view resolver. Его нужно создавать в контексте Spring'а, иначе он не работает
@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix("");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return freeMarkerViewResolver;
}
```

Кастомный view resolver будет возвращать кастомные view. Используя настоящий `FreeMarkerViewResolver`, мы резолвим базовый view и view, который хотим в него вставить:

```
class FreeMarkerWrappedViewResolver extends FreeMarkerViewResolver {

    private FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver;

    public FreeMarkerWrappedViewResolver(FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver) {
        this.freeMarkerViewResolver = freeMarkerViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        View content = freeMarkerViewResolver.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
        View base = freeMarkerViewResolver.resolveViewName("base", locale);
        return new WrappedView(content, base);
    }
}
```

В кастомном view мы сначала рендерим контент в `MockHttpServletResponse`, потом этот контент заворачиваем в модель, которую скармливаем базовому view и рендерим в настоящий `HttpServletResponse`:

```
class WrappedView implements View {

    private View nestedView;
    private View wrappingView;

    public WrappedView(View nestedView, View wrappingView) {
        this.nestedView = nestedView;
        this.wrappingView = wrappingView;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return nestedView.getContentType();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse mockResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        nestedView.render(model, request, mockResponse);
        HashMap<String, Object> bodyModel = new HashMap<>();
        bodyModel.put("content", mockResponse.getContentAsString());
        wrappingView.render(bodyModel, request, response);
    }
}
```

Готово! Теперь все view будут заворачиваться в наш темплейт.

**Вариант 2: используем встроенные механизмы FreeMarker**

В FreeMarker есть механизм наследования темплейтов. В `base.ftl` задаём структуру страницы с плейсхолдерами:

```
<#macro content>
    <!-- Этот контент нам предоставит наследник -->
</#macro>

<#macro page>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Content is</p>
            <p><@content/></p>
        </body>
    </html>
</#macro>
```

А в наследнике импортируем базовый темплейт и предоставляем значения плейсхолдеров:

```
<#include "base.ftl"/>

<#macro content>
    <b>${message}</b>
</#macro>

<@page/> <!-- Не забываем включить непосредственно контент родителя -->
```

Второй вариант предоставляет больше гибкости: плейсхолдеров может быть больше одного (например, каждый наследник может независимо переопределить хедер, контент и футер). В первом варианте добиться такого будет проблематично. С другой стороны, первый вариант позволяет избежать постоянного копипаста импорта родительского темплейта. Что лучше подходит под ваши задачи - решать вам.

Comment: Второй вариант использую сейчас, но по моему это не гибкость, а костыль. Ибо если сравнивать с шаблонизацией на php, то там гораздо проще. И первый вариант кажется костылем, ведь мы используем мок, что как бы вообще не должно быть)) Но спасибо, как добраться до рендера я понял!

Comment: Может можно какой-то фильтр применить к контенту?

Comment: Насчёт мока - просто первая фейковая имплементация `HttpServletRequest`, подвернувшаяся под руку, наверняка можно найти что-то менее "костыльное". А что вы хотите фильтровать в контенте?

Comment: Я имею ввиду использовать фильтр для того, чтобы оборачивать отрендеренный шаблон в рендер другого.

Comment: Прямо сейчас проверить не могу, поэтому нижеописанное - домыслы. В теории, если до того как сделать `chain.doFilter()` фильтр запишет начало враппера, а после - конец, то может сработать. Если внутри `chain.doFilter()` не будут писаться хэдеры. Но этот подход мне кажется также костыльным, фильтр не должен заниматься рендерингом, для этого есть view.

Comment: Плюнул я на эти все шаблонизаторы и выбрал JSP :-D